# Throwing an exception from custom class library

Tags: c#

I have created a library in C# Visual Studio 2012.

In this library I have areas that intentionally throw new exceptions when conditions aren't met. I have built the library and referenced the .dll in another project.

When the library throws an exception the debugger grabs the referenced library, opens the .cs file and displays the "Throw Exception" code from the library, instead of the code that caused the exception in my project.

How can I lock the library so the debugger doesn't show the library code that threw the exception, but instead shows the project code that caused the library to throw the exception.

I have tried googling, but I am afraid my lack of nomenclature knowledge is leading me to the wrong areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark your class and/or methods with the [`DebuggerStepThrough`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute. From the docs:

> This attribute avoids having to step into compiler-provided code and only steps into developer-provided code. For example, if you are stepping through code by using the F11 (Step Into) key, the attribute will cause the step to behave like an F10 (Step Over) key for compiler-provided code. The method won’t be stepped into, but it will be executed.

For example:

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public class MyLibrary
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //Unimportant code here
    }
}
```

Alternatively, just reference your compiled library and make sure there are no PDB files for Visual Studio to read.

Comment: The DebuggerStepThrough didn't work, but changing the Debug Info in the advanced build settings from PDB to none did the trick. Thanks!